# RStudio UI with Ubuntu 14.04 system fonts under root

Tags: fonts, root, interface

I am using rstudio on Ubuntu 14.04. Without launch the rstudio via root "sudo rstudio", rstudio is not able to install the package in the native R library folder, and also cannot open project even though it can be created. So I always start rstudio via root.

However the problem is that the rooted rstudio UI no longer looks nice, especially the fonts of the drop down menus and its color.

How can I change the settings or configurations on Ubuntu to make rooted rstudio use system fonts and colors?

1. Without Root
   [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsAWD.jpg)
2. With Root
   [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WC6a.jpg)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to add images for the moment.

Comment: Can you upload an image to imgur/etc. and post the link in here?

Comment: I have uploaded the images. The main difference is the menu part.